# Shiny reactable list object in tags$button on click

Tags: shiny, reactable, htmltools

So I have a situation where I would like to use an object in a `tag$button()`. This is to work around the fact that the columns may change.

It works on the first click and then stops working and the whole table disappears on subsequent clicks.

```r
library(htmltools)

data <- MASS::Cars93[1:5, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price",
                            "Passengers", "DriveTrain", "Cylinders", "EngineSize")]

hidden_cols <- c('Passengers', 'DriveTrain', 'Cylinders', 'EngineSize')

htmltools::browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$button(
      "Show/hide more columns",
      onclick = "Reactable.setHiddenColumns('cars-vis-table', prevColumns => {
        return prevColumns.length === 0 ? [hidden_cols] : []
      })"
    ),
    reactable(
      data,
      columns = list(
        Passengers = colDef(show = FALSE),
        DriveTrain = colDef(show = FALSE),
        Cylinders = colDef(show = FALSE),
        EngineSize = colDef(show = FALSE)
      ),
      elementId = "cars-vis-table"
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out!

Just needed to use paste0() and paste() function and collapse. Basically just using paste to replicate a printed list:

```
onclick = paste0("Reactable.setHiddenColumns(
  'cars-vis-table', prevColumns => {
    return prevColumns.length === 0 ? ['",paste(hidden_cols, collapse = "','"),"'] : [] 
  })" 
)
```